# Что означает ** в коде AutoHotkey ?

Tags: autohotkey

Подскажите, что означают **D в строке с M ? Как это можно переписать на С++ либо любой другой язык на ваш выбор ?

```
  Loop, % D := N-Idx
      F3 *= A_Index, F1 *= A_Index+Idx
  M:=(F1/(F2*F3))*((T+0.000001)**Idx)*((U-0.000001)**D), X+=M*X%Idx%, Y+=M*Y%Idx%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ нашёл. Это оказалось возведение в степень.

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Variables.htm